# Visual Studio says "Unable to start debugging on the web server"

Tags: windows-7, iis, visual-studio-2010

Before I shut down my computer last night everything worked fine.  This morning I rebooted and I started getting the error message below when I tried to start debugging my web application:

[image]

What would cause this to suddenly break?  How do I fix it?

Comment: Look here, it worked for me: https://ektronaaron.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-an-authentication-error-occurred-while-communicating-with-the-web-server/#comment-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check against this Microsoft Support article:
[Error: Unable to Start Debugging on the Web Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee%28VS.80%29.aspx)

This might also be useful:
[Unable to start debugging on the web server](http://www.onlineatoz.net/onlineatoznet/forum/post/Unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Kill msvsmon.exe process and restart Visual Studio, It works for me